# Tridion 2009 - Purge Tool

Tags: tridion

When starting the Purge Tool from the Content Manager server, nothing happens except I just get a 100% CPU process which kills my server instantly, any suggestions?

It's the first time I've executed this tool so I'm not sure what's supposed to happen; does it connect to the DB immediately? - the 190 GB DB I'm lumbered with might not be helping it if that's the case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a dialog box - It can take a while to load, but in the past I have seen this to be a permissions problem. Try right-clicking on the program, and using "Run as Administrator" if you are on a Windows 2008 Server

Answer (score 3):

I have also seen this in past, you may try this with publication by publication or with limited number of folders/structure group.
Yes purge tool use the database immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The Purge tool starts out by trying to "consume" your blueprint structure. It does this in  a pretty cumbersome way however, it will get there in the end. Just leave it to run, it will get there.

Answer (score 2):

The Purge tool doesn't connect to the db directly. It uses the Tridion API. (Of course, Tridion then goes to the database.)

On starting, the Purge tool will load all your publications, which it then displays for you. If you have a lot of publications, and a slow system, this can take a while.

If there is a permissions problem, I'd expect it to be one of Tridion permissions, so ensure that the account you are running as it a Tridion administrator.